# How to iterate the formData with for loop?

Tags: javascript, form-data

It is simple that i want to iterate  formData with js.
An example to iterate the formData object located here.
[to iterate formData in msdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries)
I create my iterate way according to the sample code.

```js
 
function show()
{
    var formData = new FormData( document.querySelector("#myForm") );
    for(var pair in formData.entries())
    {
        console.log(pair[0]);
        console.log(pair[1]);
    }
} 
ob = document.getElementById("submit");
ob.addEventListener("click",show);
```

```html
 
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="addr">
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

To type `test1` in the first input and `test2` in the second input,then click `submit`  button.

The expect  output in chorme's console

```
name
test1
addr
test2
```

The actual output in chrome's console.

```
n
e
```

How to fix my code to iterate the formData  with for loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are seeing `n` and `e` because the `entries()` method returns an iterable object with a `next` method and you are looping over that object with a `for/in` loop, which is meant to iterate the properties (keys) of an object. Since you are looping the correct number of times for your form data (2), the `for/in` loop is iterating over the name of the key (`"next"`), as a string, twice in that object.

```js
console.log(new FormData().entries());
```

Instead use a `for/of` loop which is what is shown in the documentation, which will iterate using the iterator object returned from the `entries()` method call.

```js
function show(){
    console.clear();

    var formData = new FormData(document.querySelector("#myForm"));
    
    for(var pair of formData.entries()){
        console.log(pair[0], pair[1]);
    }
    
    event.preventDefault();    
} 
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", show);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="text" name="addr">
<input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('screen', false);
    formData.append('animation', false);

for (let [key, val] of formData.entries()) {
                console.log(key, val);
            }
```